# Query a Linked Server with Excel Connection

Tags: sql, excel

In the past, I have been querying various different databases (let's call them DB1, DB2, and DB3) by using Data->From Other Sources->From SQL Server in Excel. However, I want to be able to perform just one query (say, DBMaster) and using this to populate my data.

My thoughts: Use linked servers. I create DBMaster with linked servers to DB1, DB2, and DB3. However, I do not know how to access those individual databases from Excel. When I connect to DBMaster, I only get the tables on that database, not the tables on the linked servers. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782

Comment: Marth, I'm attempting to do somewhat the same.  Did you get this figured out?  I've tried connecting to [LinkSvr].[db], [LinkSvr].[db].., LinkSvr.db ... with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You just  need  to connect your  master  database   and  exceute your  query  from there.

Just  remember  to  put  the server  name before  database  name  in  your  sql  in FROM  clause like  :

[SERVER].[DATABASE].DBO.[TABLE_NAME]